# Accessing An ArrayList from a method in a different class

Tags: c#

I'm working on my very first project outside the college.
I have two classes. In first one I have a method which adds strings to an arraylist.
In the second class I would like to access the arrayList from the method in previous class, and get elements of it.

How could I do that ?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using .NET 1.1 i would avoid `ArrayLists` and use their strongly typed counterparts [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

You need to make the method [`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx) in class 1. Then you can access it from class 2 if it is [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) or if you have an instance of class 1.

For example:

```
public class Class1{
    public List<String> getList()
    {
        // create the list and return it
    }
}

public class Class2{
    Class1 firstClass{ get;set; }
    void foo()
    {
        // now you can access the List<String> of class1 via it's instance
        List<String> list = firstClass.getList();
        foreach(String s in list)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may expose the ArrayList as a static property in the first class and then you can access that property from the second class.

```
public class First
{
    public static ArrayList MyList { get; set; }
}

public class Second
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //First.ArrayList will give you access to that class
    }
}
```

Best is **not to use ArrayList at all** (if you are using .Net 2.0 or higher) instead use [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which is type safe

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use a readonly property which exposes the arraylist, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private ArrayList FArrayList;
    public ArrayList ArrayList { get { return FArrayList; } }

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public class First
{
    public ArrayList MyList;
    public First()
    {
       MyList = new ArrayList();
    }
    public void AddString(string str)
    {
       MyList.Add(str);
    }
}
public class Second
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
       First f = new First();
       f.AddString("test1");
       f.AddString("test2");
       f.AddString("test3");
       ArrayList aL = f.MyList; // you will get updated array list object here.
    }
}
```